# Cannot configure nor start MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.5, configuration

On a brand new Kubuntu 14.04 install, I ran `sudo aptitude install  mysql-server-core-5.6`. The install could not complete due to dependencies of some KDE packages on `mysql-server-core-5.5`, which would have been replaced. Now when I run `sudo aptitude install mysql-server-5.5` I get this error after specifying a password:

```
Configuring mysql-server-5.5
Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user
An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened
because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.
You should check the account's password after the package installation.
Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.
```

I have in fact read `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian` but there was nothing relevant for my situation. The MySQL log helps:

```
$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log 
140818 10:17:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140818 10:17:16 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140818 10:17:16  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140818 10:17:17 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:17:17 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
140818 10:17:17 [ERROR] Aborting

140818 10:17:17  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140818 10:17:18  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:17:18 [Note]
```

However I cannot find in which script the `--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` option is set. I tried to start `mysql` without `service` to avoid the `--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` option but it still won't start:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
dotanco+ 25458  0.0  0.0  11748   928 pts/4    S+   10:30   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 25470
140818 10:30:54 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
140818 10:30:54 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
140818 10:30:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140818 10:30:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

[1]+  Done                    sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

$ ps aux | grep mysql
dotanco+ 25810  0.0  0.0  11748   932 pts/4    S+   10:31   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

The error tells me to `Remove all --log-error configuration options`. I therefore edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and commented out the following line:

```
log-error  = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Now I get no error but still cannot log in:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 26558
140818 10:34:37 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
140818 10:34:38 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140818 10:34:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

[1]+  Done                    sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**What might be the issue?** How should I proceed?

**EDIT**

I've now commented out the `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp` line in `my.cnf`. Here is the entire file, minus header comments:

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf 

[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

#log-error      = /var/log/mysql/error.log

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

symbolic-links=0

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

This is what happens when I try to run MySQL:

```
$ sudo echo 1 >> /var/log/mysql/error.log

$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log 
140818 10:31:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140818 10:31:50 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] Aborting

140818 10:31:50  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140818 10:31:51  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:51 [Note] 
140818 10:31:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
1

$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start

$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log 
140818 10:31:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140818 10:31:50 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] Aborting

140818 10:31:50  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140818 10:31:51  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:51 [Note] 
140818 10:31:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
1

$ grep explicit_defaults_for_timestamp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/init.d/mysql /etc/default/mysql
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:#explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
grep: /etc/default/mysql: No such file or directory
```

As can be seen, nothing new is written to the logs, and the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` option is not set anywhere.

I was able to reinstall `mysql-server-core-5.5` but that did not resolve the issue:

```
$ sudo aptitude reinstall mysql-server-core-5.5
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  mysql-server-core-5.5 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,213 kB of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Get: 1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-server-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [3,213 kB]
Fetched 3,213 kB in 1s (3,163 kB/s)                
(Reading database ... 217167 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package mysql-common (5.6.20-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...

$ sudo service mysql status
mysql stop/waiting

$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start

$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log 
140818 10:31:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140818 10:31:50 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
140818 10:31:50 [ERROR] Aborting

140818 10:31:50  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140818 10:31:51  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
140818 10:31:51 [Note] 
140818 10:31:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
1
```

That `1` on the last line of the log was added earlier with `echo`, and indicates that nothing new was added to the log.

Comment: when you run netstat -tlpn, do you see the port 3306 for MySQL?

Comment: @CraigEfrein: No, port 3306 is not being listened to. I even restart the system to see if MySQL would start on boot, but it didn't.

Comment: And the --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp, possible places to look, if you haven't already. /etc/mysql/my.cnf, /etc/init.d/mysql and /etc/default/mysql

Comment: Thank you. The string `timestamp` was found only in `etc/mysql/my.cnf` and I've comented it out. Yet, I still get the same mention of it in the log.

Comment: Is there a my.cnf in your home directory?

Comment: @Vérace: No, there is neither `my.cnf` nor `.my.cnf` in `/home/dotancohen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed `mysql-server-core-5.6`, which partially failed or partially installed.

The [`-explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) is only for MySQL 5.6. Its probable that the partial installation of `mysql-server-core-5.6` added this option. I am going to suggest now that you remove any trace of `mysql-server-core-5.6` and reinitialize the data directory.

1. kill any running mysqld processes:

   ```
   ps aux | grep mysql
   kill pid
   ```
2. Uninstall the `mysql-server-core-5.6` packages:

   ```
   apt-get remove mysql-server-core-5.6
   ```

   A list of files is [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mysql-server-core-5.6)
3. Reinitialize the database directory:

   A. `rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql/*`

   B. `mysql_install_db /var/lib/mysql`
4. Comment out the `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/` option in `my.cnf`

---

Kill any existing MySQL Process and then start MySQL using the [`skip-grant-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) option.

A. Get the exact path of the mysqld daemon:

```
which mysqld_safe
```

B. Run MySQL without grant tables:

```
/mysqld_safe_directory/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
ex /bin/mysqld_safe
```

C. Make sure mysql is listening:

```
netstat -tlpn
```

you should see port 3306.

D. If so, log into MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
```

E. Set new password:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: Thank you Craig. I was able to reinstall `mysql-server-core-5.5` but that did not resolve the issue. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @dotancohen, updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. I completely removed any trace of 5.6, rm'ed both `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/log/mysql`. The `mysql_install_db` command failed because `resolveip` was not found. I then installed `mysql-server-5.5` (which apparently is not installed along with `mysql-server-core-5.5`) to get `resolveip`. During the install of `mysql-server-5.5` I got the `Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user` error again, back to square one!

Comment: @dotancohen updated answer. This depends on whether or not MySQL is actually listening.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, `mysqld_safe` dies right away: `40818 16:52:52 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/bruno.err'.` , `140818 16:52:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql` , `140818 16:52:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended`.

Comment: @dotancohen All MySQL processes where stopped? ps aux | grep mysql

Comment: Yes, of course! Only the grep process itself shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16510/discussion-between-craig-efrein-and-dotancohen).

Comment: On Debian 9.4, for step 3b it seems like the directory name argument should be `--datadir=`, with it as written you get`'/usr/sbin/mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is '/var/lib/mysql')` and it fails, but if you remove it runs fine and uses that as the default anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have this line in my.cnf

```
[pol@localhost mysql-5.6.19-linux-x86_64]$ grep expli my.cnf
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp = TRUE
```

I think that the my.cnf parameters should use hyphens and not underscores.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I had that line as well though I missed it. Now, mysql won't start but nothing is written to the logs. I'll update the question.

Comment: I know that on Xubuntu (can't stand Unity desktop!) I had the devil of a time with issues like this. I now build from source - if you're interested, I'll write out how I do it **exactly**. What I do is adapted from [here](https://mariadb.com/blog/compiling-debugging-mariadband-mysql-eclipse-scratch-part-2-compile-eclipse) after much trial and error. It's a bit more work than sudo apt-get install xxx, but at least I know where my files are and what to do if things start to go wrong!

Comment: Thank you, if I cannot get through this then I'll try the instructions that you link to.

Comment: Well, that's for people who want to compile and run mysql through eclipse - I've adapted it for someone who just wants to run mysql normally. Why are you using 5.5?

Comment: Actually, I would prefer 5.6 and I don't use eclipse.

Comment: As I said, I use it without Eclipse. Just cmake, make and make package and then install the binary. MySQL's binaries have default locations - and since I want to run multiple versions, it makes life easier.